# Invariants associated to a principal bundle whose total space is a symplectic manifold acted symplectically by group structure

Tags: dg.differential-geometry, riemannian-geometry, sg.symplectic-geometry, principal-bundles

**The  following question - proposal came  to my mind  about  4 years  ago but I  did not find any solution to this  question and did not find any answer via  e-personal  comunication with some researchers so I  present these questions here hope I can  find some  ideas or  collaborator for  work. Your  comment  or  message  to my  personal email are very  appreciated.**

Let  we  have  a  $G$-principal  bundle  $\pi: M\to X$  where $G$ is  a  Lie  group  with Lie  algebra $\mathfrak{g}$. Moreover assume that  $M$ is  at the same time   a symplectice  manifold  and the  action of  $G$ on $M$ is  a  symplectic  action.  Let $\phi: M\to \mathfrak{g}^ *$ be the momentum map whose differential is   $d \phi: TM\to M\times \mathfrak{g}^*$.   We  equip $M$  with an invariant metric then we  get the  corresponding LC connection. This  connection   gives us a  connection form $\omega: TM\to \mathfrak{g}$  which can be  considered as a bundle morphism $\omega: TM\to M\times \mathfrak{g}$. We  consider the adjoint operator $\omega^*:M\times \mathfrak{g}^* \to T^*M $ of the  connection form. The  composition $\omega^* \circ d\phi: TM\to T^*M$ defines a $2$  linear  map $\alpha:TM\times TM \to \mathbb{R}$. So  we  are  interested to study this  $2$ linear map. If it is  not  necessarily an anti symmetric $2$ linear map, we  denote again  by $\alpha$ its  antisymmetric  component. Is  $\alpha$  a  closed $2 form$? What is its cohomological class? Is it a trivial  class? Is  it  cohomologue to the original symplectic $2$ form of $M$?
To apply this  idea to the  tangent frame  bundle  of  a  manifold it is first necessary  to ask that   for what type of manifolds $M$ the total space of the tangent frame bundle $GL(M)$ admits a symplectic structure? When the  base  space is a  symplectic manifold then it is  guaranteed that the  total space has a symplectic  structure,  but what about the general case? After we  determine the  manifolds whose total space of the Frame bundle is a  symplectic manifold  then we study the  above mentioned $2$-form $\alpha$ which is  a byproduct of  combination of  principal and  symplectic structures.

Comment: If I'm not mistaken, then $\alpha(X, Y) = \sigma(X^v, Y)$, where $\sigma$ is the symplectic form and $X^v$ denotes the vertical part of $X$ wrt to the connection. So unless you assume some compatibility of the connection with the symplectic form, I don't see how to answer any of your questions.

Comment: @TobiasDiez Thank you very much for your comment. I think about some compatibilities.

Comment: @TobiasDiez what kind of compatibility  do you siggest?

Comment: For example, you might want to require your metric to be compatible with the symplectic form so that the LC is a symplectic connection, $\nabla \sigma = 0$.

Comment: @TobiasDiez  Yes  I  see ,thank  you